# place the picture on facebook wall

Tags: php, image, api, facebook

How can I place the picture on facebook wall via API??
Thank`s

Comment: You probably want the 'facebook' tag on this.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```